# manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs”

Tags: android, android-manifest

I just made an app for notification, and when I run it, it shows

> "manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs”.

I already clean and rebuild project. But not work. And the log cat is too large so I can't include it.

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:replace="android:icon"

    package="shiweichen22gmail.notification">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="shiweichen22gmail.notification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="shiweichen22gmail.notification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label= "@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="shiweichen22gmail.notification"/>
                </intent-filter>>
            </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GCMPushReceiverService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            </service>
        <service android:name=".GCMRegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add this lines in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<permission
    android:name="your_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="your_package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<receiver
    android:name="your_package.NotificationReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

        <category android:name="your_package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```